# Is it necessary to use -l library option when using -c 'compile-only' option (and at what stage is fPIC option necessary)?

Tags: c, gcc

I am encountering this a lot while cleaning up some makefiles. Is this just lazy makefile craftsmanship or is there a purpose for the `-l` options when invoking the compile-only `-c` option?

For some further context: lets say `foo.c` does indeed use some function in `libbar.so`.  However, when compiling `foo.c` using the `-c` option, is it necessary to include `-lbar` or is it sufficient to simply include the necessary path for `bar.h`?  For some further context still, let's say `foo.o` will be bundled up with some other output at a later stage whereupon the '-lbar' option would then be invoked.  I am not sure it matters, but let me also stipulate that `libbar.so` is a custom or otherwise non-system library.

And I realize I maybe committing a posting foul, but this is a related question: when in the above process is the `-fPIC` option necessary?  Can I wait until bundling `foo.o` with its other associated output files along with the aforementioned '-lbar' option, or is 'fPIC' necessary when first compiling `foo.c` even if I am using the `-c` option?

Comment: `-l` is only used when linking.  From `man gcc`: *"Search the library named library when linking. [...] The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC."*.  Therefore if you are not linking, you do not need to specify `-l`.

Comment: Experimentation is a good way to learn. What happens when you remove the `-l` from the `-c` command line? Does anything break?

Comment: The fact that SO choses the font in which capital I (as in Indigo) is absolutely indistinguishable from lower-case l (as in love) makes the question super confusing.

Comment: `-fPIC` means 'generate position-independent code', and as such is a compiler flag, so include it when compiling with `-c`

Comment: On the experimentation question:  yes, I have done some experimentation; and thus far things do compile using `-c` option without the `-l`, but I worry about the insidious error that triggers a cascade of build and integration test failures somewhere down the line.  I didn't write the particular unit tests for this code and have little confidence in their coverage (there is much work still to be done, I know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-l` is only necessary when you link objects into executable or shared object or compile directly into executable or shared object. But with -c ("compile only") you compile into object file, so `-l` is not necessary here. `-fPIC` - you need to use it when you compile into object file or directly into executable. It is not needed at linking stage. So you put it where you also use `-c`.